# Allow and Prevent postback in javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I was trying to validate dates using java script on button click event.If validation returns false post-back should be prevented and if returns true post-back should be allowed.

The problem is that post-back is occuring even if the validation returns false.....

I'm new to javascript.Kindly give me any solution.....

Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateDate() {

        var GridView = document.getElementById('GridView1');           
        var i = 1;
        var rows = GridView.rows.length;           
        for (var j = 0; j < rows - 2; j++) {
            i = i + 1;              
            var FromDate = new Date(document.getElementById('GridView1_ctl0' + i + '_txtFrom').value);
            var ToDate = new Date(document.getElementById('GridView1_ctl0' + i + '_txtTo').value);
            if (ToDate < FromDate) {
                document.getElementById('GridView1_ctl0' + i + '_txtFrom').focus();
                alert('ToDate is less than from date');
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;      
    }
</script>
```

I've called javascript on pageload event

```
this.btnSave.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ValidateDate();");
```

Comment: try "onclick". It's the correct way to specify the attribute, even if it may work with the capital C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to specify `return`

You should try with:

```
this.btnSave.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return ValidateDate();");
```

You are returning the value back from the ValidateDate() so for such a condition you need to specify this at the time of function call, and when it returns false then it stops the execution further..

Comment: thank u for the correct answer..Can u explain how is it working ??

Comment: I appended the explanation..@ksg